# Different output when printed vs saved as a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a summary data frame which has averages, mins and maxes ([see original post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448793/summarising-data-frame-rows-based-on-name-prefix)). I can print the output I want, but whenever I try to save it to a data frame, I only get the averages, not the mins and maxes. I've tried updating R and tidyr, and I can't think of anything else that would cause this. I've tried using `as.data.frame()` and that doesn't help.

```
#example df
df <-  read.table(header=TRUE, text="shop    tables  chairs  beds
                  jim-1   2   63  31
                  jim-2a  10  4   16
                  jim-2b  32  34  43
                  jen-1   32  90  32
                  jen-2   73  91  6
                  jen-3   35  85  65
                  sam-a   72  57  72
                  sam-b   18  48  11
                  sam-c   34  49  79
                  paul-1  43  49  23
                  paul-2  76  20  23
                  paul-2a 34  20  8")

#create a grouping to allow me to average out group values
shop_group = sub("-.*", "", df$shop)

#print a summary table (works fine)
aggregate(df[,2:4], list(shop_group), 
          FUN = function(x) summary(x)[c(4,1,6)])

#generate a summary data frame (doesn't work, only gives me the averages, not the mins and maxes)
summ_df= aggregate(df[,2:4], list(shop_group), 
                 FUN = function(x) summary(x)[c(4,1,6)])
```

Comment: seems to work fine for me.

Comment: So your summ_df has 10 columns? I've run it on two other computers, and the data frame I get always has 4 columns

Comment: yep; 10 columns. Have you completely cleared your environment, and then just run the code you've supplied here?

Comment: Restart your R session, then re-run this code without loading any external packages.

Answer (score 1):

it works fine..

```
> aggregate(df[,2:4], list(shop_group), 
+           FUN = function(x) summary(x)[c(4,1,6)])
  Group.1 tables.Mean tables.Min. tables.Max. chairs.Mean chairs.Min. chairs.Max.
1     jen       46.67       32.00       73.00       88.67       85.00       91.00
2     jim       14.67        2.00       32.00       33.67        4.00       63.00
3    paul       51.00       34.00       76.00       29.67       20.00       49.00
4     sam       41.33       18.00       72.00       51.33       48.00       57.00
  beds.Mean beds.Min. beds.Max.
1     34.33      6.00     65.00
2     30.00     16.00     43.00
3     18.00      8.00     23.00
4     54.00     11.00     79.00
> summ_df= aggregate(df[,2:4], list(shop_group), 
+                    FUN = function(x) summary(x)[c(4,1,6)])
> summ_df
  Group.1 tables.Mean tables.Min. tables.Max. chairs.Mean chairs.Min. chairs.Max.
1     jen       46.67       32.00       73.00       88.67       85.00       91.00
2     jim       14.67        2.00       32.00       33.67        4.00       63.00
3    paul       51.00       34.00       76.00       29.67       20.00       49.00
4     sam       41.33       18.00       72.00       51.33       48.00       57.00
  beds.Mean beds.Min. beds.Max.
1     34.33      6.00     65.00
2     30.00     16.00     43.00
3     18.00      8.00     23.00
4     54.00     11.00     79.00
>
```

Comment: dim(summ_df) tells me that I have a 4x4 matrix. If I view summ_df in the RStudio preview window, it gives me a 4x4 matrix with columns for "Group.1", "tables", "chairs" and "beds". But if I just type summ_df or write a csv, it will give me the whole data frame. Seems very weird, but apparently not reproducible. Thanks anyway.